# Can a Domino file upload control put its attachment in a specific field?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, attachment

I have a classic Domino app (not XPages... ugh!) that needs to have several file upload controls, with each one corresponding to a particular field.  If I upload a file using file upload control #1, it should go into (e.g.) RFS_1, and if I use control #2 it should go into (e.g.) RFS_2.

Since Domino just attaches all the files to the document, I see no obvious way of putting them each in their own field.

Comment: Everyone who has done Domino development for any length of time knows all its advantages.  But there are thousands of paper-cut annoyances like this one that make me hate it.  Ruby FTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the code in the wqs to move the file you can add some extra fields to control where each attachment goes.  What we've done before is..

- have some upload controls on a form
- have a rich text field per upload control to hold the attachment
- have a "type=hidden" field on the form per upload control
- in the onchange event of the upload control have some javascript to write the filename of the chosen file into the corresponding hidden text field

then in the wqs agent you can loop through the hidden fields, find those file attachments on the doc and write them into the corresponding rich text field

shout if you want me to add any more detail

Comment: This is pretty close to what I came up with Friday after asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no simple way.  Here is some code, though, that should help you move the file to the rich text item during the WebQuerySave event:

http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256BC80071114F